# Xslt transformation using powershell

Tags: powershell, xslt

I need to run a Xslt transformation using a powershell script that recursively for all the object *.xml:

- Load the file
- Transform it
- Save the output with the same file name in the same path.

I thought something like this

```
FolderToCheck = "MyFolder"
Get-ChildItem $FolderToCheck -Filter *.xml | ForEach-Object {
    # declare Xslt script for transformation
    [Xml]$Xslt_script = Get-content 'MyScript.xslt'
    # read xml
    $File = [xml](Get-Content $_.FullName)
    # Run the transformation
    $xslt = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform
    $xslt.Load($Xslt_script)
    $xslt.Transform($File,$File)
    
    }
```

I'm always getting error. What is it wrong? Can you suggest what to amend?

thanks

Comment: You say you are getting an error. Please post the actual error message.

Comment: As commented, show the exact error message. I suspect that XslCompiledTransform doesn't want to read from and write to the same file as XSLT is not meant to have side effects, so in terms of shell scripting you might want to check whether you can't write to a temp file and then use shell scripting to rename the output/remove the input. I also think the `Transform` overload taking only two arguments expects two files names, so your best bet would be to not use the line `$File = [xml](Get-Content $_.FullName)` but simply try `$xslt.Transform($_.FullName, $_.FullName + '.result')`

Comment: Sorry you're right this is the errorr I 'm getting

Exception calling "Transform" with "2" argument(s): "Could not find file 'C:\Users\gdiprima00\System.Xml.XmlDocument'."
At line:9 char:1
+ $xslt.Transform($File,$File)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Martin Honnen suggestion, I have amended a little bit my code as follows:

```
 Get-ChildItem $FolderToCheck -Filter *.xml | ForEach-Object {
     # declare Xslt script for transformation
     [Xml]$Xslt_script = Get-content 'MyScript.xsl'
     # Create Output File Name
     $dir = $_.DirectoryName
     $BaseName = $_.Basename
     $OutputFileName = $_.DirectoryName + '\' + $_.Basename + '_v2.xml'
     # Run the transformation
     $xslt = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform
     $xslt.Load($Xslt_script)
     $xslt.Transform($_.FullName, $OutputFileName)
     rm $_.FullName
     }
```

With this I'm able to generate my *_v2.xml file and then delete the original file.

Thanks a lot